# What type of content/format is this (Response that i am getting from an API)?

Tags: java, object, format

What type of object/content is the following piece of response from an API

The Content-Type of the API response is coming as `text/HTML`

```
a:3:
{s:6:"status"
;i:1;
s:3:"msg"
;s:22:"Transaction is Pending"
;s:6:"result";
}
```

Ideally I am expecting a way to make this object into a JSON object or a way in which Java is able to handle such objects.

Comment: Looks like some custom format invented by that API, so what does the **API Documentation** say the format is?

Comment: @Andreas the documentation does not have anything describing the format of the response. The API url is a php file.

Comment: Then you should contact the developers of the API, and ask them to complete the documentation.